# Copy stdout and stderr to a log file, show on console only stderr output and log stderr messages into another file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, output

I have a situation I need the output redirection in a bash script in the following way:

1. On the console only errout messages should be shown
2. Errout messages should be also logged into one specific file like errout.log
3. Stdout and errout messages should be both logged into the file, like allout.log
4. Not so important, nice to have, but possibly achievable with only a lot of effort - the order in the allout.log should be possibly very similar or the exact order of the messages as they appear.

I did not found the exact same situation in other similar asked and answered questions.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh it could be `foo 2>&2 2> err.log > all.log 2>&1`.

In bash, this might work:

```
foo 2>&1 >> all.log | tee -a all.log err.log >&2
```

or

```
{ foo >> all.log; } 2>&1 | tee -a all.log err.log >&2
```

Comment: Nice -- I really need to get more practice with some of the redirection cases.

Comment: Do you have any information source, which explains understandably the redirects in all complexity? It would be for me also nice to improve my knowledge in this area and from manual pages or generally found pages unfortunately I did not get enough information to be able to write such thing by myself...

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't think of a shell-based solution, so I suggested this.  Others have provided much better shell-based solutions.  I'll leave this here just in case someone finds it interesting, but the other answers are better.

Here's a C program that'll do what you're after:

```c
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// Some wrappers around system calls to hide error handling
static void Pipe(int pipe_fds[]);
static pid_t Fork();
static void Dup2(int old_fd, int new_fd);
static void Execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <script> [<arg>, ...]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a pipe to handle stdout
    int out_pipe[2];
    Pipe(out_pipe);

    // Create a second pipe to handle stderr
    int err_pipe[2];
    Pipe(err_pipe);

    if (Fork() == 0) { // Child
        // Wire the child's stdout stream to the write end of out_pipe
        close(out_pipe[0]);
        Dup2(out_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(out_pipe[1]);

        // Wire the child's stderr stream to the write end of err
        close(err_pipe[0]);
        Dup2(err_pipe[1], STDERR_FILENO);
        close(err_pipe[1]);

        // Invoke the target program with the remaining args
        Execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    }

    // Parent only from here on out

    // Close the write ends of the pipes
    close(out_pipe[1]);
    close(err_pipe[1]);

    // Set up the file descriptors and events we're interested in monitoring
    struct pollfd poll_fds[] = {
        { .fd = out_pipe[0], .events = POLLIN },
        { .fd = err_pipe[0], .events = POLLIN },
    };

    int incomplete_fds = 0;

    while (incomplete_fds != 2 && poll(poll_fds, 2, -1) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            // Is this file descriptor readable?
            if (poll_fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
                char buffer[4096];
                const ssize_t num_bytes = read(poll_fds[i].fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

                // (3) write both stdout and stderr our stderr
                write(STDERR_FILENO, buffer, num_bytes);

                if (i == 1) { // if this was a write to stderr
                    // (1) write standard error to out stdout
                    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, num_bytes);
                }

            }

            if (poll_fds[i].revents & (POLLHUP | POLLNVAL)) {
                // Don't expect anything more from this
                poll_fds[i].events = 0;
                poll_fds[i].fd = -1;
                ++incomplete_fds;
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void Pipe(int pipe_fds[])
{
    if (pipe(pipe_fds) < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static pid_t Fork()
{
    const pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return pid;
}

static void Dup2(const int old_fd, const int new_fd)
{
    if (dup2(old_fd, new_fd) < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static void Execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[])
{
    execvp(file, argv);
    perror("execvp");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The program takes the application that you want to run as an argument, along with any arguments that you want to pass that application.  It creates two pipes, one to capture the content that the application writes to `stdout` and another for `stderr`.  It then `fork()`s, connects the pipes to the output streams of the child, then invokes the application with any arguments.

The parent process can then read from those pipes; it uses `poll()` to wait for activity on any of those file descriptors.  Anything the program reads from either the `stdout` or `stderr` streams of the application, it writes to `stderr`.  Anything the program reads from the `stderr` stream of the application, it writes to `stdout` (This seems backwards, but it simplifies redirection).

I can compile the C program with

```
$ gcc prog.c -o pipe_wrapper
```

Now, say I have something that generates output to both `stdout` and `stderr`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# ex.sh

echo stdout
echo stderr 1>&2
```

Then I can run:

```
# Note that the content written to stderr appears on the console
$ ./pipe_wrapper ./ex.sh 2> allout.log | tee errout.log
stderr
$

# That content written to stderr is captured in errout.log
$ cat errout.log
stderr
$

# And that everything written to either stdout of stderr is captured
# in allout.log
$ cat allout.log
stdout
stderr
$
```

I cannot guarantee that this will preserve ordering; if the application writes to both `stderr` and `stdout` in quick succession, this program might process the content written to `stdout` before the content written to `stderr`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is impressive solution... 
But if there still could be achieved some solution only with bash, it would be nice - the infrastructure where it should be used is not under my control and I am not sure the customer would allow us to run there arbitrary programs from our side. I will check it, thank you very much for your effort!
I thought my unsuccessful tries to achieve it only with bash are caused only by my poor linux knowledge, had no idea such thing could be so complicated for solution with bash only...